# Advanced ORM usage for constraint filtering by an annotated value

Tags: python, django, django-orm, python-3.7, django-2.2

I have the following Query/(ies) that I have constructed:

```
users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)

date_range = [start_date, timezone.now()]

results = SurveyResult.objects.filter(
    user__in=users,
    created_date__range=date_range,
).annotate(
    date=TruncDate('created_date'),
    total_score=Sum('score'),
    participants=Count('user'),
).values(
    'survey',
    'user',
    'date',
    'total_score',
    'participants',
).order_by(
    'date',
)
```

A quick print of each result in the resulting QuerySet as:

```
for result in results:
    print(results)
```

...outputs data as this:

```
{'survey': UUID('eb51368e-994a-4c0b-8d8a-e00ed20b5926'), 'user': UUID('25afbbfd-bddf-4fe8-bbac-758bd96093b0'), 'date': datetime.date(2019, 7, 26), 'total_score': 90, 'participants': 1}
{'survey': UUID('09947780-8d60-499f-87e3-fc53a9490960'), 'user': UUID('6afdea22-ea10-4069-9e7b-43fb6955ce0e'), 'date': datetime.date(2019, 7, 26), 'total_score': 17, 'participants': 1}
{'survey': UUID('890d0a21-6e27-457f-902e-e2f37d2fad6c'), 'user': UUID('d98684f7-97ab-49d7-be50-0cc9b6465ef5'), 'date': datetime.date(2019, 7, 26), 'total_score': 35, 'participants': 1}
{'survey': UUID('890d0a21-6e27-457f-902e-e2f37d2fad6c'), 'user': UUID('d98684f7-97ab-49d7-be50-0cc9b6465ef5'), 'date': datetime.date(2019, 7, 27), 'total_score': 62, 'participants': 1}
```

The eagle eyed amongst you might notice that the last two records are pseudo-duplicate on the 'user' and 'survey' keys, but not on any of the other.

My question is: how the heck do I remove the records from this record set (either using the Django ORM Query I have constructed or in a standard pythonic way) where the 'survey' and 'user' keys match - only keeping the most recent record according to the 'date'...so leaving me:

**Expected Outcome:**

```
{'survey': UUID('eb51368e-994a-4c0b-8d8a-e00ed20b5926'), 'user': UUID('25afbbfd-bddf-4fe8-bbac-758bd96093b0'), 'date': datetime.date(2019, 7, 26), 'total_score': 90, 'participants': 1}
{'survey': UUID('09947780-8d60-499f-87e3-fc53a9490960'), 'user': UUID('6afdea22-ea10-4069-9e7b-43fb6955ce0e'), 'date': datetime.date(2019, 7, 26), 'total_score': 17, 'participants': 1}
{'survey': UUID('890d0a21-6e27-457f-902e-e2f37d2fad6c'), 'user': UUID('d98684f7-97ab-49d7-be50-0cc9b6465ef5'), 'date': datetime.date(2019, 7, 27), 'total_score': 62, 'participants': 1}
```

**Things I Have Tried**

I was thinking perhaps utilising something like this:

```
unique = { result['survey'] and result['user'] : result for result in results }.values()
```

Comment: What is your DB backend?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Postgres

Comment: If you have all the data already, just do this in python: loop through the results and discard all duplicate scores but the last one.

Comment: I have tried looping over the data, but it is not quite discarding what I want.

Comment: If your results are sorted correctly (as you show above, i.e. all duplicate records are in the date order) then it's just a matter of creating a new dictionary with the keys being the combination of survey_id + user_id and assigning the values to the new dict one by one (the ones with same combination overwrite the previous one). Then you flatten the dictionary again by removing the keys. Which is what you seem to be doing, so it's not clear what exactly went wrong when you did that.

Comment: Note that if a user gives two scores on the same day, your current query picks one of them, but not necessarily the last one for that day. So if that's by chance also the last day, you're not sure the score is the last score for that user.

Comment: Don't use `a and b` as key with two uuids. It always returns `b`, so you're now just keeping one score per user, not per user and survey. Use `f"{a}+{b}"` for example

Comment: @dirkgroten Not sure what you are asking me to do.

Comment: Added it on top of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the results you want apparently, so you can also do this in python, which is almost what you proposed:

```
unique = {f"{result['survey']}+{result['user']}": result for result in results}.values()
```

The reason your try wasn't working is: you should use a unique key that represents both survey and user. With `and` you're just getting `result['user']` since `a and b` will return `b` if both are `True`.

But, I believe your ORM query has an issue. You need to ensure you get the `latest_score` given by a particular user, not one of the scores on the last day on which a score was given (say you have two scores with different `created_date` (different times) but, after `TruncDate`, they have the same `date`). In order to get the last score, you should try this:

```
results = SurveyResult.objects.filter(
    user__in=users,
    created_date__range=date_range,
).values(
    'survey', 'user'  # group by unique survey, user pair
).annotate(last_score=
    Window(expression=LastValue('score'),
           partition_by=[F('user'), F('survey')],
           order_by=F('created_date').asc(),
    )
).annotate(date=
    Window(expression=LastValue(TruncDate('created_date')),
           partition_by=[F('user'), F('survey')],
           order_by=F('created_date').asc(),
    )
).values(
    'survey', 'user', 'date', 'last_score'
)
```

`total_score` and `participants` don't really make sense since the score is just the one row where the user last gave a score for a particular survey; and participants is always 1.

Those would make sense if you aggregate by survey and date instead of survey and user.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: The data is not in the correct format, and hasn't passed a single test.